# Conditional statement on two variables taking dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code where a variable (Holdout_date) takes a date in a particular cell and then there is a block of code which is conditioned on the statement: if another variable (lastdte) takes a date equal to Holdout_date then activate sheet(3). However while running this code i am getting error 424(Object required). How do I get past this? Thanks in advance

```
Dim lastdte As Date
Dim Holdout_date As Date
Holdout_date = Range("A13")
Range("D1048576").End(xlUp).Select
lastrow = ActiveCell.Row
lastdte = Range("B" & lastrow)
If Not lastdte Is Holdout_date Then  
Sheet(3).Activate
End If
```

Comment: First of all it will be: Sheets(3).activate. Second is convert lastdte and Holdout_date to long then compare it directly like 'if lastdte = Holdout_date then'

Comment: Thank you for the correction. It has worked!

Comment: Two important links for you. [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Thank you. The links were very useful!